# Python: Get value of env variable from a specific .env file

Tags: python, environment-variables, python-os

In python, is there a way to retrieve the value of an env variable from a specific .env file? For example, I have multiple .env files as follows:

.env.a
.env.a
...

And I have a variable in .env.b called INDEX=4.

I tried receiving the value of INDEX by doing the following:

```
import os

os.getenv('INDEX')
```

But this value returns None.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It might be easier if you do something like `os.environ['INDEX'] = '4'` in your `*.py` file

Comment: There is no built-in support for .env files in python. But you could use a package like `python-dotenv` that can add support for those. https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a job for [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) or [ConfigObj](https://configobj.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). ConfigParser is built into the Python standard library, but has the drawback that it REALLY wants section names. Below is for Python3. If you're still using Python2, then use `import ConfigParser`

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('env.b')
index = config['mysection']['INDEX']
```

where env.b for ConfigParser is

```
[mysection]
INDEX=4
```

And using ConfigObj:

```
import configobj
config = configobj.ConfigObj('env.b')
index = config['INDEX']
```

where env.b for ConfigObj is

```
INDEX=4
```

Comment: I am getting 'keyerror' when I use config parser in the way you described

Comment: I had an error in my import statement and some extra spaces. I've edited my answer. 'key error', however, points to a typo in your code or env.b file. Python is case sensitive.

Comment: Does 'env.b' have to be in the same directory as the file you are running the code from? My env.b is 3 directories above. In that case, do I have to specify like, config.read(/path/to/env/env.b)?

Comment: You'll have to either specify absolute path (/path/to/env/env.b) or relative path (../../../env3). I just did a test on Windows and relative path works. You need ` ../ ` for every directory up you want to go.

Answer (score 8):

Python has a specific package named python-dotenv to use keys stored in the .env file.
Here is how we can use a key in the .env file. First, create a key like this in the .env file

```
demokey=aaa2134
```

To load this key in the python file we can use this code:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
import os
x = os.getenv("demokey")
print(x)
```

In Python 3.x , since its not available natively

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

Comment: Python 3.X doesn't have `dotenv` as a native library.

Comment: pip install python-dotenv in Python 3.x

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `environs` library and os library to pull from `.env` files.

Would look something like:

```py
import os
from environs import Env

env = Env()
env.read_env() # read .env file, if it exists

os.getenv("TEST_API_KEY")
```