# How to import numbers from a text file to variables?

Tags: python

I have a task in which you need to take numbers from another text file for the legendary fizzbuzz. I previously wrote a program that takes numbers from input. How can I now include reading numbers from another file into it?

```
print("Fizz:")
fizz = int(input())
print("Buzz:")
buzz = int(input())
print("3 number:")
num = int(input())
i = 1
while i <= num:
    if i % fizz == 0 and i % buzz == 0:
        print("FB")
    elif i % fizz == 0:
        print("F")
    elif i % buzz == 0:
        print("B")
    else:
        print(i)
    i+=1
```

Comment: I recommend just looking up python input/output and files. This is an introductory topic and lots of content online that shows you how to do this.

Comment: There are many tutorials on reading and writing files in Python. SO is not a substitute for learning the basics.

Comment: Do you want to [read a file into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list?rq=1)?

Comment: Possibly more precise duplicate: [How should I read a file line by line in Python?](/questions/11555468)

Comment: I just can’t understand how to do it right. File contains 20 strings with 3 numbers each. How can I assign first number as fizz, second as buzz and 3 as 3 number. And in each string

Comment: [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) is built into the standard library that comes with Python. It's designed to read and write [ini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) style files. It's a convient way to save and retrieve variables. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63019760/9705687) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73420515/9705687) for how to get started.

Comment: in question you should show what you have in file because all depends on if you have numbers in separated lines or in one line (separated by space or comma)